# Class not found magento2

Tags: magento2

How does one get a detailed description of an error from the system.log file in Magento 2?

I'm only able to see

> [2016-06-14 11:11:01] main.CRITICAL: Class tglssearch does not exist [] []

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

magento2 logs are handled by **Monolog** so that is default.

Magento Log Details resides under

1. `<magento-root>/var/log/*`
2. `<magento-root>/var/report`

You have check the detailed error in **httpd logs**(apache server logs). In httpd logs you can able to see the **exact line** of where the errors occur.

I am using apache with fedora, in my case httpd logs resides under `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: Hi i have no files under var/report. And how to get a detailed description of the errors from var/system.log file in magento 2, It says only class not found, i want to know from which path location or which file

Comment: have you check apache log?

Comment: yes in apache error log nothing related to the project